# Finding the minimal set with maximal coverage

Tags: r, set

I have a number of ids where each is associated with a number of hits. Here's how the data looks like:

```
ids <- LETTERS[1:4]
all.hits <- paste("h",1:50,sep=".")

set.seed(1)
df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(1:length(ids), function(i){
  hits <- all.hits[sample(50,as.integer(runif(1,5,10)),replace = F)]
  return(data.frame(id=rep(ids[i],length(hits)),hit=hits,stringsAsFactors=F))
}))
```

Given `number.hits` I'm looking to find the minimal set of hits such that each `id` is covered by at least `number.hits` of those hits and this set has the maximal representation of ids.

So if for example `number.hits <- 2`, the set will be:

```
c(h.10,h.19,h.42,h.50)
```

Because `h.10` is covered by ids: `A,B,C` then `h.19` which is covered by ids: `A,C,D`, then `h.42` which is covered by ids: `A,D` and then `h.50` which is covered by ids: `B,C`. Thus `A` is covered 3 times (>= `number.hits`), `B` is covered twice (>= `number.hits`), `C` is covered 3 times (>= `number.hits`), and `D` twice (>= `number.hits`).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this with `library(tidyverse)`?

```
number.hits <- 2
df %>% group_by(hit) %>% tally() %>% filter(n >= number.hits)
# A tibble: 5 × 2
hit     n
<chr> <int>
1  h.10     3
2  h.19     3
3  h.42     2
4  h.44     2
5  h.50     2

number.hits <- 3
df %>% group_by(hit) %>% tally() %>% filter(n >= number.hits)
# A tibble: 2 × 2
hit     n
<chr> <int>
1  h.10     3
2  h.19     3
```

I got a few more two count hits than you expected, not sure if I missed something in your conditions.

Comment: Close. I edited my question because the result I specified was missing h.42. In your solution only A and C are covered >= number.hits, whereas B and D are covered only once.

Comment: isn't B in h.10 and h.50  and D in h19 and h.42?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
number.hits <- 2
setDT(df)[, if(.N >= number.hits) .N, by = hit]
#    hit V1
#1: h.19  3
#2: h.44  2
#3: h.10  3
#4: h.42  2
#5: h.50  2

number.hits <- 3
setDT(df)[, if(.N >= number.hits) .N, hit]
#    hit V1
#1: h.19  3
#2: h.10  3
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
subset(aggregate(.~hit, df, length), id >= number.hits)
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun. The problem is that this only ranks the hits by the number of ids they cover but doesn't check if each id is covered >= number.hits. In order to get A-D covered at least twice the set will have to be: h.10,h.19,h.42,h.50. I'm not sure this is solvable without an optimization solver.